# Installshield 2010 skins are not working on Windows 7

Tags: windows, installshield

In our company we used to work with Installshield 2010 on a Windows 2008 server. Due to restrictions we had to remove that installation and re install it on my local PC.

I have installed Installshield 2010, SP1, prereqs, prereqsdotnet and the skin customization kit on my Windows 7 computer.
Everything works fine except the skins. The layout is always the same regardless of which skin I select. (built-in or custom skin)
This worked fine on the Windows 2008 server so I think it's OS related.

Has anyone experienced a problem like this with Installshield?